# Drawing a DOT within a cells UIImageView's UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage, cgcontext

Currently, I am attempting to draw a simple dot inside of a cell's `UIImageView`'s `UIImage`. I am attempting to accomplish the same thing that the calendar application the iPhone has when an event is represented by a calendar.

```
[[event calendar] CGColor]
```

is an `EKEvent` object which logs `UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.509804 0.584314 0.686275 1`

I attempt to create a small dot whose color is  `[[event calendar] CGColor]`. Heres what I am currently trying to do:

```
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, [[event calendar] CGColor]);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(contextRef,(CGRectMake (12.f, 5.f, 4.f, 5.f)));
CGContextDrawPath(contextRef, kCGPathFill);
CGContextStrokePath(contextRef);
cell.imageViewPic.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

But here are the errors I'm getting:

```
 MYSCHEDULER[21445] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
 MYSCHEDULER[21445] <Error>: CGContextAddEllipseInRect: invalid context 0x0
 MYSCHEDULER[21445] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
 MYSCHEDULER[21445] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong... Why is the context invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, you're trying to get an image of the drawing you do and then add it to the imageViewPic. Here's what you should do to get it working:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(5.0f,5.0f)); 
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, [[event calendar] CGColor]);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef,(CGRectMake (0.f, 0.f, 5.f, 5.f)));
UIImage *drawingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

cell.imageViewPic.image = drawingImage;
```

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(); is giving me an error. "Too few arguments to function call, single argument 'size' was not specified"

Comment: I forgot to add the size in the first line. Now it will work. Please check my edit.

Comment: Yeah i just looked it up and added the size of the cells imageViewPic... THANK YOU @CODENAMELAMBDA1 You rock!

Comment: Thank you for the appreciation! :)